# .NET Standard library - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching'

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, .net-standard

I build a library using the latest .NET Standard version. It all works OK.

The problem occurs when I add the `System.Runtime.Caching` NuGet package. I tried to add all stable versions from 4.5 to 4.7. I get the following error for any version, when trying to use classes from this package.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: What packages do you use apart from this one?

Answer (score 5):

In Asp.Net core app, i was referencing some libraries and it caused an issue when i tried use those libraries.

I had to add System.Runtime.Caching, because my libraries were unable to find them, which is not available by default in asp.netcore web api project. Hope this will help someone. You can install them from nuget package manager.

[image]

Comment: For me it was a slightly different exception, but the same solution worked. Exception: PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Runtime.Caching is not supported on this platform. My .Net 6 project dependent on a .Net Standard 2.0 library which was throwing this.  Looks like the library assumed this assembly to be available (it probably was in older versions). So I explicitly added System.Runtime.Caching 6.0.0 package, and that solved the issue. Hope it helps someone in future!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall System.Runtime.Caching package with NuGet package manager and close your visual studio. Than install this package again.
If it's not fixed the problem , check your csproj file and references in your project for version conflict or mismatch.